# When to give up on polymorphism in order to generalize a solution?

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have an interface called SqlPhrase:

```
interface SqlPhrase extends SqlElement {
    void include(SqlPhrase ph);
    SqlRoot obtainRoot();
    List<SqlElement> obtainElements(); 
    boolean hasElements();
    SqlPhrase safeCopyOf();
}
```

The key here is the `safeCopyOf()` method which I'll discuss in just a bit.  I have a skeletal implementation for this interface that is shared by all concrete classes that implement this interface.  The skeletal implementation happens to encapsulate all the state that is used by the concrete classes.

```
@Mutable
static abstract class AbstractSqlPhrase implements SqlPhrase {

    private final List<SqlElement>  m_elem;
    private final SqlRoot           m_root;

    AbstractSqlPhrase()
        { m_elem = new ArrayList<>();  m_root = null; } 
    AbstractSqlPhrase(SqlRoot r) 
        { m_elem = new ArrayList<>();  m_root = r; }
    :
    :
}
```

The issue is the `safeCopyOf()` method which I would like to go ahead and include in anticipation that this non-thread safe class may need to be used in a concurrent environment.  I have already decided not to write the class to be inherently thread safe (it would be hard) as I am expecting thread confinement to be the usual use of instances of these classes anyway.

Here's the question:

Because all of the state is encapsulated by the `abstract` `class`, I would like to implement the `safeCopyOf()` method in the skeletal implementation.  I can't, though, because I need to have an instance of the concrete subclass which, at this level, I don't know.

Polymorphism is the solution, but I don't want to implement the same code in all the concrete subclasses, particularly as all the state I need to perform the operation is contained in the skeletal implementation.

Another solution is to use the `instanceof` operator and have the instance test itself for each concrete subclass.  I believe this would work, but I don't want to go this route since it would impose a maintenance burden.

Am I missing an elegant solution here?

Comment: You give up on polymorphism when the parrot refuses to change.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Cloneable.  here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4329993/2446277

Comment: Cloning an object with final Collection fields will lead to serious heartache.  You'll end up with two or more objects sharing a Collection!